# Form Journey Tracking using google analytics

Tags: forms, google-analytics

Is there anyway, using google analytics, to track a user's journey/selections through a long form so I can see where they drop off?

I've created a 'contact us' form which starts with drop down menu which requires the user to make a choice i.e. apply for job, apply for funding etc. and then each option requires the user to fill out a form, which is completed over serval steps.

Is there a way to track a user's individual form choices from their initial selection on the Contact Us page through to the form being submitted? That way I could see where in the form journey the users are dropping off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is a multi-page form, then you can use Goal Funnel tracking to obtain reports which will help you understand how users fail to complete the form:

http://www.google.co.uk/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=55515

The Regular Expression matching in Goal Funnels is quite useful if you have different paths or different form URLs for the same goal.  You could also track multiple page views per actual URL, if you wanted to monitor the users who move onto a different step on a single URL.

If you need to analyze how users complete a particular form, you could use Event Tracking to record when each field is completed.  You will need to carefully think about how you wish to use Event Tracking to obtain the information you require.

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

But Google Analytics is not good at tracking individual users' behavior.  You may wish to take a look at [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/) if you want to do more advanced form usage analysis.

Comment: Thanks Big Tony. It's what I came up with after checking around but it's always good to ask a question here.

Comment: This is great. However, how do I track the successful submisison of the page rather than the display of the next step. Let's say my multi-page form has three steps, and afterwards it redirects to my main app page (there is no "thank you, you're finished" step). How would I track the completion of the multi-page form? Is there a way to submit synthetic tracking message from the server to GA, reliably? Can you submit server-side events?